# Как установить цвет тексту Hint в SearchView?

Tags: android, android-search-view

Как мне представляется, для того чтобы назначить цвет `Hint`-тексту необходимо извлечь из `SearchView`  `EditText`.

```
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    if (searchEditText != null) {
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
```

В моем случае `searchEditText != null` - равен `false`, то есть `searchEditText  null`.

Догадываюсь, что неправильно указываю `R.id.search_src_text`. Тут в зависимости от библиотек поддержки разные пути, например:

```
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

Но мой `SearchView` из `import android.widget.SearchView;`. И вроде как отображается от 16 по 25 `API`.

Возможно проблема в том, что у меня два `SearchView` в рассматриваемом `Activity`. Если проблема в наличии двух `SearchView` как добраться до их `EditText`?

В конечном итоге мне нужно просто поменять цвет `Hint` в `SearchView` (программно).

Comment: Ваш `SearchView` стоит в `ActionBar/Toolbar` или как отдельная `View`?

Comment: Попробуйте `android.R.id.search_src_text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился следующим образом.

```
SearchView searchName = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview_name_id);
SearchView searchLastName = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview_lastname_id);
```

Упакуем в метод:

```
private void setSearchViewHintColor(SearchView searchView, Color hint){

     searchView.setQueryHint("Все найдется...");
     int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
     View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
     if (searchPlate!=null) {
         int searchTextId = searchPlate.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
         TextView searchText = (TextView) searchPlate.findViewById(searchTextId);
                if (searchText!=null) {
                    searchText.setHintTextColor(hint);
                }
            }
}
```

[Источник](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/pro-tip-customize-the-android-search-view-widget/#)

Вызовем:

```
setSearchViewHintColor(searchName, Color.White);
setSearchViewHintColor(searchLastName, Color.White);
```

Мысль о том, что несколько `SerchView` могут конфликтовать при вызове `R.id.search_src_text` не подтвердилась. Ведь `search_src_text` в пространстве `id` должен быть уникальным. Почему так будем выяснять.

Comment: Если вы сделали утилитный метод, то сделайте цвет как параметр метода.

Comment: Согласен с вами

Comment: Ну и пару советов.. Опять же утил-метод не должен ничего лишнего делать, например, `setQueryHint` там точно не должно быть, это не относится к установке цвета подсказки. Ну, думаю, вы поняли. И `id` давайте внятные :) а то запутаетесь

Comment: спасибо за советы. id как раз таки были поданы так специально.

Comment: `Color` не очень подходит. Можно я добавлю в код методы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, буду рад

Comment: Пожалуй, нет)) Я хотел добавить метод куда можно передать `R.color..` но так как нужен контекст, это требует дополнительных манипуляций. Ну и ещё, наверное, разделить надо метод на два: `setSearchViewBackgroundColor` и `setSearchViewHintColor`.. Ну, фиг с ним :D

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете `SeatchView` из библиотеки `AppCompat`, то получить `EditText` можно так:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

А если `android.widget.SearchView`, то так:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.R.id.search_src_text);
```

Comment: '@Flippy: во втором варианте в `android.R.id.search_src_text` выделяется часть `search_src_text` красным цветом. (Android Studio)

Comment: возможно проблема в том, что `SearchView` два?

Comment: Да хоть 100500. Вы ищете то в каком-то определенном: `searchView.findViewById`

Comment: А что студия говорит?